# "My unqualified host name (endor) unknown;"

Tags: sendmail

My server is taking around 1 minute to send emails. I had a look in the logs and I see this:

> My unqualified host name (endor)
>   unknown; sleeping for retry

Cant figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> your host file entry should have your simple hostname after the
>   others:
>
> `/etc/hosts`:
>
> `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost myhostname`

[Reference](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-85365.html)